# Inequality using second derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I was reading a complicated proof in a book. Without going into irrelevant details, the objective is to prove the following:

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two concave functions on $[0,1]$ such that for every $x\in(0,1)$

1. $f(x)\geq 0$, $g(x)\geq 0$.
2. $f(0)=g(0)=f(1)=g(1)=0$.
3. $f''(x)\leq 0, g''(x)\leq 0$ and $f''(x)\geq g''(x)$.

Then $f(x) \leq g(x)$.

I do not understand how this follows. The author painstakingly proves the third point above, all to prove the conclusion. He doesn't appear to use the first derivative anywhere. I attempted a taylor series expansion of $f(x)-g(x)$ to get
$$f(x)-g(x) = f(0)-g(0) + x(f'(0)-g'(0)) + \frac{x^2}{2}(f''(u)-g''(u))\\
= x(f'(0)-g'(0)) + \frac{x^2}{2}(f''(u)-g''(u))$$
for some $u\in(0,x)$.
If anything, this appears to be somewhat contradictory to what needs to be shown. I'd appreciate it if someone could throw more light on this matter since it doesn't seem straightforward.

The book I was reading was

> Holevo, Alexander S. Quantum systems, channels, information: a
>   mathematical introduction. Vol. 16. Walter de Gruyter, 2013.

Page 79-82. Theorem 5.9.

Comment: $f''(x) \le 0$ is equivalent to concavity. Is there a typo?

Comment: No. I have already mentioned that the functions are concave.

Comment: that's why I asking ... usually assumptions are not redundant :D

Comment: Maybe it means that the second derivatives exist.

Comment: @Juanito: Yeah. As I mentioned earlier, I rephrased the original problem. So a redundancy did happen as I could simply have mentioned that second derivatives exist. In any case I was able to solve the problem seconds after posting it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it.

Let $h(x) =f(x)-g(x)$. Since $f''(x) \ge g''(x)$, $h(x)$ is convex. Since $x \in (0,1)$,
$$h(x) \leq xh(1) +(1-x)h(0) = 0$$

Hence proved.